# Homophobia should be discouraged

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Questions about homophobic phrases, such as [Is this a slang, and possibly derogatory term, for "lesbian"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/is-this-a-slang-and-possibly-derogatory-term-for-lesbian) , is ok.

But homophobia on the part of stack exchange users should be discouraged. For example, if someone were to imply that a same-sex relationship is purely about sex, or that homosexuality and prostitution are synonymous, then that should be discouraged.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, homophobia should be discouraged on JLU. So should be eating kittens and kicking babies.

While obviously concurring with the fact that homophobic behaviour (just like any other inappropriate or bigoted behaviour) is not welcome on JLU (and in fact, against the user terms), I completely fail to see the point of your post.

I have yet to notice a single outright homophobic comment anywhere on JLU. And while there might have been occasional snickering on random mature content-related topics (not specifically linked to discussions of homosexuality), none of what I have seen ever crossed the line from questionable taste into anything that demands action (and I am quite easy on the trigger with that one).

In fact, the post you link to is a model of restraint and I do not see a single out-of-line comment from any of the contributors there.

In conclusion, I really don't know what your motivations for this post are, but it looks more like strawman building than actual community contribution...

Comment: I do not know your intent of listing homophobia, eating kittens, and kicking babies on the same line.  That analogy seems distracting at best, offending at worst.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: in Dave's defense, "eating kittens" is an English idiom meaning "being evil for the sake of being evil".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: I did not know that.  That cleared up my confusion.  Thanks!

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: my point was simply to say that the OP addressed something so blatantly obvious that I did not see its point, given the absence of specific cause.

Answer (score 3):

Andrew, while I respect everyone's right to choose their own life style, unfortunately languages tend not to.

If it so happens that a word for homosexual in Japanese is synonymous with a word for prostitution there is nothing we can do about it.

The language represents the views of the culture that speaks it, not our views.

So long as the answers and question into words like this do not themselves contain clear predigest intent, I think they need to be allowed.

To further illustrate my point consider the following. If you joined a site for learning English and asked about "the N word", do you think that your question should be deleted? or that people should tell you exactly what the word implies and why it is that way?